# Watir and Cucumber. link not clickable

Tags: html, cucumber, watir

I am new to Watir and Cucumber, and I am trying to run an automation to create Live IDs. Below is the HTML for the link that I want to click, the "New" text is what it is showing on webpage. It would lead me to the form to add new contact to my Live account.

```
<ul class="c_cc" role="presentation" styple="overflow:visible;">
    <li class="c_sm c_mcp" id = "new">
        <a id href="#" class="c_nobdr t_prs">
            <span class="is_c" dir="ltr" style="padding-right: 5px;">
                <img class="is_img" src="https://p.pfx.ms/is/invis.gif" onload="this.onload=null;$Do.when('$IS.Init',0,this);" style="width:26px;height:26px;background-position:-1px -1px;background-image:url('https://p.pfx.ms/h/command4.png');" alt="New contact" title />
            </span>
            "New"
        </a>
        <span class="c_ms"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

the watir code I wrote to click the "New" is below:

```
@browser.div(:id, "c_header").div(:id, "c_cb0").ul(:class, "c_cc").span(:text, "is_c").when_present.click
```

I get this error:

```
Watir::Wait::TimeoutError: timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for {:id=>"is_c", :tag_name=>"span"} to become present
```

Then I tried below code:

```
@browser.div(:id, "c_header").div(:id, "c_cb0").ul(:class, "c_cc").span(:text, "New").when_present.click
```

but this code does not really clicking on the "New" link, so the next form won't show up, and the rest of the code cannot run. Does anyone know any solution to this problem?

I found out a new window popped up, so it could not find the element in the old window. Thanks guys for helping.

Comment: How many elements on your page have the text "New"? Can you show the entire html for the "c_header" div? Your last code should not work - there is no `span(:text, "New")` in your html. That might mean that you are clicking some other element that says "New".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first watir code snippet, a `:text` locator is being used for the `.span` method instead of a `:class` locator.  For example:

```
browser.ul(:class, "c_cc").span(:text, "is_c").exists?     #=> false
browser.ul(:class, "c_cc").span(:class, "is_c").exists?    #=> true
```

In the second watir code snippet, a `:text` locator with a value of `"New"` is being used for the `.span` method.  In this case, a `.link` method should be used.  Additionally, the string includes double-quotes, so the double-quotes must be escaped if enclosed in another set of double-quotes (or enclose in single-quotes).  For example:

```
browser.ul(:class, "c_cc").span(:text, "New").exists?      #=> false
browser.ul(:class, "c_cc").span(:text, "\"New\"").exists?  #=> false
browser.ul(:class, "c_cc").link(:text, "\"New\"").exists?  #=> true
browser.ul(:class, "c_cc").link(:text, '"New"').exists?    #=> true
```

So, one of the following examples should work:

```
browser.link(:text, "\"New\"").when_present.click
browser.link(:text, '"New"').when_present.click
browser.link(:class, "c_nobdr t_prs").when_present.click
```

Comment: Thanks orde. I tried the link(:text, "\"New\"").when_present.click. it timed out. Also, link(:class, "c_nobdr t_prs") timed out too. error produced: Watir::Wait::TimeoutError: timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for {:class=>"c_nobdr t_prs", :tag_name=>"a"} to become present..          when I tried link(:text, "New") it didn't produce error but neither click on the link......maybe the link is not visible?

Answer (score 0):

Wow. This is old and I have encountered the same behavior. First, this is in a Cucumber step definition. The following works perfectly in open Ruby code. It simply refuses to function as a step.

It finds the link in the table and clicks it. Click doesn't function.

```
link = browser.table(class: 'alert-table').tbody.rows[1].cells.last.link(text: 'View')
# <Watir::Anchor: located: false; {:class=>"alert-table", :tag_name=>"table"} --> {:tag_name=>"tbody"} --> {:index=>1} --> {:index=>-1} --> {:text=>"View", :tag_name=>"a"}>
link.click
```

Ruby 2.4
watir (6.16.5)
regexp_parser (~> 1.2)
selenium-webdriver (~> 3.6)

Comment: And my problem is a misunderstanding of spreading steps across multiple files. I had instantiated a browser in each file, thus spreading the commands between two different browser instances. I need to construct a method to establish the browser instance once and pass that between all steps files.